# Is it possible to add basic authentication to an existing asp.net app without touching existing code like htaccess in Apache/PHP

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'd like to add a login/password form (basic authentication popup in browser is ok don't need more) in existing asp.net app I didn't develop but for which I have access to deployment directory.

I'd like to be able to do this without entering their source code only web config or iis config something like htaccess in Apache/PHP/

Does this exist in IIS/ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic authentication could be configured at IIS level:

- [Configure Basic Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Basic Authentication in IIS 6.0 (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/abbca505-6f63-4267-aac1-1ea89d861eb4.mspx)

Comment: Thanks I'll try on IIS 7 if it doesn't work I will come back to haunt you :)